# Привязка к статическому свойству: не подхватываются изменения

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть `ComboBox`, у которого я хочу установить свойство `IsEnabled` в зависимости от значения поля статического класса. Но при изменении `IsConnect` свойство `IsEnabled` у `ComboBox` не изменяется. В чем проблема?

xaml:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding
    Source={x:Static local:Settings.IsConnect},
    Mode=TwoWay, Path='.', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

cs:

```
static class Settings
{
    private static bool _IsConnect { get; set; }
    public static bool IsConnect
    {
        get { return _IsConnect; }
        set
        {
            _IsConnect = value;
            NotifyStaticPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: почему оно должно меняться и зачем вам метод `NotifyStaticPropertyChanged`?

Comment: откажитесь от статического свойства, перейдите на нормальный Singleton, у которого свойство IsEnabled будет динамическим, а у класса в котором будет это свойство будет реализация INotifyPropertyChanged и тогда все будет нормально меняться.

Comment: @tym32167, это специальный механизм оповещения об изменении статических свойств, доступный с WPF 4.5 (см. ссылку в моем ответе). Но да, ТС, если есть возможность отказаться от статики — лучше сделать это.

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, не приходилось пользоваться к счастью :)

Answer (score 3):

Специальный механизм оповещения об изменении статических свойств, который вы используете (который доступен начиная с WPF 4.5) работает только с привязкой такого типа:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:Settings.IsConnect)}"
```

С привязкой `{Binding Source={x:Static ...}}` он не работает.

<sub>[WPF 4.5: Binding and change notification for static properties](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties)</sub>