# Как создать привязку между свойством статического класса и элементом управления textBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

Господа. 
Я создал XAML и хочу, чтобы на ней отображалась актуальная информация документа, которая содержится в статическом классе Document. Отображение, понятное дело, происходит в textBlock'ах.

Меня мучает вот такой вопрос: 
Каким образом привязать к элементу управления textbox свойство статического класса, к примеру symbAmount и нужно ли будет заводить отдельную стринговую переменную для привязки данных?

Document.cs:

```
static class Document
    {
        private static string text = "null";

        public static int symbolsAmount { get; set; } = 100;
        public static int wordsAmount { get; set; }

        public static string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }
            set
            {
                text = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
...
 Title="MainWindow" Height="290" Width="260">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="290"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="39*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="134*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="81*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="symbAmountPinned_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Symbols amount:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="wordsAmountPinned_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Words amount:" HorizontalAlignment="LEft" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="wordsCheckedPinned_texBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Words checked:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="wordsCorrectedPinned_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Words corrected:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="senAmountPinned_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Senteces amount:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>



        <TextBlock x:Name="symbAmount_textBlock" Height="20" Width="50" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="197" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="wordsAmount_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="42" HorizontalAlignment="LEft" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="wordsChecked_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="wordsCorrected_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="senAmount_textBlock" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Height="28" Width ="225" Margin="14.5,162.667,14.5,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Value="15"/>

        <Grid x:Name="percent_indicator" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="65.5,165,18.5,100" Grid.Row="1" Width="50">
            <Label x:Name="num_label" Height ="Auto" Width="35.807" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=progressBar}"/>
            <Label x:Name="perc_label" Height ="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Content="%" Margin="28,0,0,0" />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Лучше избегать статики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class:

```
public class VersionManager
{
    public static string FilterString {get; set;}
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource VersionManager}, Path=FilterString}"/>
```

ответ взят с: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property

кейворды для гугления: `c# xaml static binding`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте следующий код:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="symbAmount_textBlock" Text="{Binding Path=(local:Document.Text)}" ...
```

где `local` — пространство имен, в котором находится класс `Document`.

Такая привязка может даже отслеживать изменение статических свойств, см. связанный вопрос: [Привязка к статическому свойству: не подхватываются изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907303/218063)

Но на самом деле я бы вам рекомендовал отказаться от использования статических свойств, потому что "глобальное состояние = зло". А еще у вас проблемы с пониманием верстки в WPF. Впрочем это всё не относится к вопросу.

Comment: Простите, но что вы имели ввиду ввиду, когда написали про проблемы с пониманием?

Comment: Ну например, что неправильно позиционировать элементы с помощью Margin, вроде такого: `Margin="0,110,0,0"`

Comment: В таком случае лучше будет использовать дополнительные столбцы и ряды, я правильно вас пониманию?

Comment: Да, ну и бросается в глаза установка одинаковых значений для свойств, стоит вынести это в отдельный стиль. И не рисуйте контролы мышкой, пишите разметку вручную

Comment: Спасибо за уточнения)