# Обновление информации на форме вовремя вычислительного процесса

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, асинхронность, static

Всем Добрый вечер

У меня имеется такой вот xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Source = {x:Static local:Document.SymbolsAmount}, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Такой вот класс Document:

```
 public static class Document
    {
    public static int SymbolsAmount { get; set; } = 100;
}
```

И такой код для xaml`a:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Work();
        }

        private async static void Work()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => IncreaseWords());
            MessageBox.Show("Increasing was finished!");
        }
        private static void IncreaseWords()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Document.WordsAmount += 10;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос, почему при изменении свойства класса Document в асинхронной операции не обновляется приемник textblock?

Comment: Вам же в предыдущем вопросе дали ответ с ссылкой на эту проблему. Или читаем только один ответ?

Comment: Извините, не увидел

Comment: Во первых, вам нужен INotifyPropertyChanged для оповещения интерфейса об изменений свойства из кода. Во вторых вам нужно убрать статик, УБЕРИТЕ ЕГО, очень сильно советую, иначе будете потом ловить уйму костылей. Не ленитесь инициализировать классы! В третьих, если вы все же решите оставить статик, то мы смело можем закрывать дубликатом на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907364/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ скорее всего будет дубликатом тк как я привел этот примитивный пример, чтобы понять как работать со статическим классом в большей программе, где данный класс служит контейнером статических полей, которые являются общими для всей программы.