# Реализация INPC для статических свойств

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть класс, содержащий статические переменные, например

```
public class Configs {
    public static string MyBestString { get;set; }
    public static MyClass MyConfigs { get;set; }
}
```

Реализуем для него INPC:

```
public class Configs : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private static string _MyBestString { get;set; }
    public static string MyBestString { 
        get => _MyBestString;
        set => {
            _MyConfigs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyBestString");
        }
    }

    private static MyClass _MyConfigs { get;set; }
    public static MyClass MyConfigs { 
        get => _MyConfigs;
        set => {
            _MyConfigs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyConfigs");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName) {
        var e = PropertyChanged;
        e?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Однако тут мы сталкиваемся с проблемой, а именно RaisePropertyChanged не статический. Поискав, я [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663457/8361539) решение, применил его, но, забегая вперед, оно не работает.
Теперь в VM для окна вставляем `public string MyBestStringForWindow => Configs.MyBestString;`. И в самом окне привязываемся к этому свойству. Однако его изменение не обновляет привязанный элемент.

Что я делаю не так?

---

P.S. Привязки напрямую к статическому свойству класса `Config` в данном случае лучше избегать, ибо, скорее всего в `get'тере` `MyBestStringForWindow` будет происходить обработка элемента.

Comment: Исходя из чего свойства класса `Configs` объявлены статическими?

Comment: @XelaNimed к ним есть доступ из любого места программы. Они должны быть одинаковы. Конфигурация у программы одна же.

Comment: Для этого не нужно объявлять их статическими. Вы можете создать экземпляр класса при старте программы, сохранив его затем в публичном свойстве. И в этом случае, к нему тоже будут иметь все доступ.

Comment: Ок, допустим, вы правы. А где хранить ссылку на публичное свойство так, что бы она была доступна откуда угодно?

Comment: В WPF - App.xaml.cs, в WinFroms - Program.

Comment: Вы про class `App`? Если да, то - если объявить в нём не статический экземпляр класса, то мы не сможем добраться до него из любой части программы, ибо нужно будет создавать экземпляр `App`, а в нём уже другой экземпляр класса конфигов. Если объявить статический экземпляр класса, то мы не сможет реализовать у него INPC (смотрите мой вопрос) (Вообще мы в принципе не может реализовывать интерфейсы в `App`, но ладно). Возможно я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Свойство в App статическое (например App.Config), свойства в классе Config - не статические. Запускается программа - создаёте экземпляр класса Config и сохраняете его в статическом свойстве класса App.

Comment: Про привязку к статическим свойствам смотрите здесь вопрос и ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907364/218063

Comment: Да, ваши решения помогли. Если хотите - оформите, как ответ.