# DataGrid ComboBox как установить ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня есть DataGrid с DataGridComboBoxColumn, так же у меня есть переменная, в которой содержатся нужные мне варианты для КомбоБокса. Как их соединить?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MondayGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="327" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223" Margin="-4,-4,-4,-3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Время" CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Предмет" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" Width="150" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Subject}" ItemsSource="{Binding FormSTRs}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

переменная -

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> FormSTRs { get; set; }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Привязка к статическому свойству: не подхватываются изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907303/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.FormSTRs}}"
```